# Диагностика GUI RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, многопоточность, gui

Приложение наглухо зависает при входе через RDesktop (стандартный удаленный рабочий стол Windows) на удаленный Windows Server 2008 (вышел, зашел - ого, зависло). Проблема сводится к такому простейшему коду:

```
  ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback((obj) =>
  {
     var richTextBox = new RichTextBox();

     while (true)
     {
       richTextBox.AppendText("a");//источник зла
     }

   }), SynchronizationContext.Current);
```

richTextBox изначально в дочернем потоке, поэтому InvokeRequired=false, конфликта с GUI не должно быть.
Вопрос-в чем может быть проблема, с чего начать диагностику?

### Update

еще такой взгляд на проблему:

```
  ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback((obj) =>
  {
       var richTextBox = new RichTextBox();

       //Thread.Sleep(10000);//вышел-зашел в RDesktop -все нормально
       richTextBox.AppendText("a");//источник зла
       Thread.Sleep(10000);//вышел-зашел в RDesktop- приложение виснет

   }), SynchronizationContext.Current);
```

### Update 2

[Такая же ошибка возникает при экранной заставке (splash screen)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659283/interface-freezes-in-multi-threaded-c-sharp-application/4660095#4660095).

Еще по теме:

- [Debugging Windows Forms Application Hangs During SystemEvents.UserPreferenceChanged](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsui_team/archive/2012/10/31/debugging-windows-forms-application-hangs-during-systemevents.userpreferencechanged.aspx)
- [Mysterious Hang or The Great Deception of InvokeRequired](https://web.archive.org/web/20171107074638/http://www.ikriv.com:80/dev/dotnet/MysteriousHang.html)
- [Memory Leak in ToolStripTextBoxControl](https://memprofiler.com/articles/memory-leak-in-toolstriptextboxcontrol)
- [What is UserPreferenceChangedEventHandler in C# winform applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137071/what-is-userpreferencechangedeventhandler-in-c-sharp-winform-applications)
- [.NET 4.0 and the dreaded OnUserPreferenceChanged Hang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077822/net-4-0-and-the-dreaded-onuserpreferencechanged-hang)

### Изначальная задача

Требуется в отдельном (не основном) потоке сформировать большой RTF. RTF необходим, так как требуется форматирование шрифта (разные размеры шрифта и проч.) Затем сохранить в файл richTextBox.Save(файл.rtf)

Comment: Э-э... а можно ли подробнее вот об этом: "richTextBox изначально в дочернем потоке". Это как?

Comment: @InterfaceUnknown наверно более правильно использовать термин "рабочий поток" -worker thread. richTextBox изначально в нем.

Comment: @PeterRybkov: А где именно виснет? Какой поток? Вы можете воспроизвести проблему под VisualStudio?

Comment: @VladD виснет в главном потоке, окно перестает реагировать на клики мыши. Рабочий поток продолжает хорошо выполняться. При дебаге из VS проблема не проявляется, возникает только при запуске релиза.

Comment: А при отладке Release-версии из-под Visual Studio?

Comment: @VladD на удаленном сервере стоит Express. Насколько знаю, там нет такой возможности.

Comment: Попытка разместить визуальный компонент, не являющийся thread-safe в потоке - это потеря времени. Работать это не будет по фундаментальным причинам. Следует переформулировать задачу и пересмотреть архитектуру приложения. Логику (получение, склеивание строк; считывание из файлов и пр.) можно вынести в поток, а результаты синхронизировать в главный поток одним из многих способов Interprocss Communication.

Comment: А вы не пробовали вынести обработку в **фоновый** STA-поток? У меня подобное срабатывало. `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` не прокатит, т. к. `ThreadPool` содержит только MTA-потоки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше сделать поток не в очереди, а напрямую `Thread.Start`. Добавьте обязательно `Application.DoEvent` в теле потока. Поток сделать *STA*.

Answer (score 3):

У меня эта (или похожая) проблема воспроизводится на Win 2008 R2, но подвисает не полностью, а секунд на 10. WinDbg показывает следующий трейс:

```
0043e8f8 779801a9 [HelperMethodFrame_1OBJ: 0043e8f8] System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOneNative(System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle, UInt32, Boolean, Boolean)
0043e9c4 70726dd2 System.Threading.WaitHandle.InternalWaitOne(System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle, Int64, Boolean, Boolean)
0043e9e0 70726d9c System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne(Int32, Boolean)
0043e9f4 6df04246 System.Windows.Forms.Control.WaitForWaitHandle(System.Threading.WaitHandle)
0043ea30 6e2657bf System.Windows.Forms.Control.MarshaledInvoke(System.Windows.Forms.Control, System.Delegate, System.Object[], Boolean)
0043ea34 6defce3b [InlinedCallFrame: 0043ea34] 
0043eabc 6defce3b System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(System.Delegate, System.Object[])
0043eaf0 6e13bf99 System.Windows.Forms.WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.Send(System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback, System.Object)
0043eb08 700c5c23 Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents+SystemEventInvokeInfo.Invoke(Boolean, System.Object[])
0043eb3c 700c5533 Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.RaiseEvent(Boolean, System.Object, System.Object[])
0043eb90 700c5123 Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.OnUserPreferenceChanged(Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
0043ebb0 7028bb60 Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.WindowProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
0043ebb4 000ca24a [InlinedCallFrame: 0043ebb4] 
0043ed64 000ca24a [InlinedCallFrame: 0043ed64] 
0043ed60 6d9c976c DomainBoundILStubClass.IL_STUB_PInvoke(MSG ByRef)
0043ed64 6d97f341 [InlinedCallFrame: 0043ed64] System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG ByRef)
0043ed98 6d97f341 System.Windows.Forms.Application+ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr, Int32, Int32)
0043ed9c 6d97efc1 [InlinedCallFrame: 0043ed9c] 
0043ee24 6d97efc1 System.Windows.Forms.Application+ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext)
0043ee74 6d97ee32 System.Windows.Forms.Application+ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext)
0043eea0 6d958a41 System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(System.Windows.Forms.Form)
0043eeb4 001e007a WindowsFormsApplication2.Program.Main()
0043f03c 71463de2 [GCFrame: 0043f03c]
```

После этого в отладке выпадает пачка исключений:

> System.ComponentModel.InvalidAsynchronousStateException
>
> An error occurred invoking the method.  The destination thread no longer exists.

Судя по всему, при удалённом входе система пытается прислать всем окнам `OnUserPreferenceChanged`. RTB - окно, и до него сообщение тупо не доходит - потому что поток, в котором RTB создан, в это время занят добавлением букв или сном.

У меня перестает подвисать, если брать поток не из пула, а создавать новый:

```
new Thread(() =>
{
    var richTextBox = new RichTextBox();

    //Thread.Sleep(10000);//вышел-зашел в RDesktop -все нормально
    richTextBox.AppendText("a");//источник зла
    Thread.Sleep(100);//вышел-зашел в RDesktop- приложение виснет

}).Start();
```

Исключения все еще видны в отладке, но при этом они выбрасываются сразу же, и зависания нет.

UP:

по UserPreferenceChanged находится описание конкретно этой проблемы:

- [Debugging Windows Forms Application Hangs During SystemEvents.UserPreferenceChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dsui_team/debugging-windows-forms-application-hangs-during-systemevents-userpreferencechanged) - с подробной инструкцией по отладке подобных проблем.
- [KB943139 :Windows Forms application freezes when system settings are changed or the workstation is locked](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/943139) - KB с описанием именно этой проблемы.

> Applications should never leave Control objects on threads without an active message pump. If Controls cannot be created on the main UI thread, they should be created on a dedicated secondary UI thread and Disposed as soon as they are no longer needed.

Так что если хотите надежного решения - запускайте вторую помпу:

```
new Thread(() =>
{
    Application.Run(new Скрытая_Форма_С_RTB_на_ней());            
}).Start();
```

и закрывайте эту форму сразу как она перестанет быть нужна.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Но по первому коду вынужден огорчить, на цикле подобном *см. самый первый пример кода* приложение тоже виснет.

Comment: по 2-му примеру кода сделал так: а)добавил в проект Form1 б) добавил в код Form1 после InitializeComponent(); *цикл из самого верхнего кода* в)добавил в код кнопки на MainForm *new Thread(() =>
            {
                Application.Run(new Form1());

            }).Start();* Profit:простите не получил, по-прежнему зависает при пере-заходе из RDesktop :(

Comment: проверьте, пожалуйста, первую ссылку-у меня 404

Comment: @PeterRybkov подправил ссылку. решение с запуском еще одной помпы должно помочь, по крайней мере оно должно убрать блокировку основной формы. Ставьте на сервер windbg, цепляйте его к приложению и смотрите трейс. Если трейс тоже будет на смене UserPreferences - делайте минимально воспроизводимый пример, и лейте его на гитхаб - я могу попробовать его отдебагать. В качестве крайней меры могу предложить взять второе решение и разбавить цикл вызовами `Application.DoEvents()` - это позволит приожению обработать события. Но это совсем костыль-костыль.

Comment: @PeterRybkov - только что заметил - код надо поставить **не в конструктор формы**, как сделали вы! а в любое событие - хотя бы в OnLoad. Иначе он вызывается до вызова Application.Run - т.е. фактически до старта помпы - и из-за этого подвисает.

Comment: хотелось бы рассмотреть проблему со стороны **отвязки RichTextBox от UserPreferenceChanged**. Есть такие [попытка1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23801597/how-to-ignore-system-messages-on-application-level-wm-settingchange-wm-winin) [попытка2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25478646/using-winforms-prefiltermessage-to-capture-and-ignore-wm-settingchange)

Comment: @PeterRybkov вы пробовали переставить код из конструктора в OnLoad?

Comment: пробовал, форма также "замораживается" на время работы цикла

Comment: @PeterRybkov выкладывайте минимальный пример куда-нибудь

Answer (score 1):

Проблема возникает от неполного понимания основ многопоточного программирования.

**В дочерних потоках не следует использовать компоненты UI, имеющие окно. Точка.**

RichTextBox порожден от `System.Windows.UIElement`, и, стало быть, имеет дескриптор окна. Большинство подобных контроллов не являются thread-safe и выполнение их кода следует дополнительно программировать.

На выполнении метода `richTextBox.AppendText("a")` из дочернего потока происходит **неавторизованное вмешательство** в исполнение кода главного потока. Результатом, как правило, является исключение.

Если уж вы их используете, то передачу результатов из дочернего потока (выполняющего логику) в главный следует запрограммировать при помощи обратных вызовов (Callbacks).

Несколько отличных статей по теме (англ. яз):

- [RichTextBox Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [How to: Make Thread-Safe Calls to Windows Forms Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Threads and Conrtols](http://ruby.fgcu.edu/courses/mpenderg/CSNotes/Threadsand%20GUIControls.html) *полный ответ на вопрос*
- [Using RichTextBox in a thread?](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/using-richtextbox-in-a-thread.1402964/)

Comment: **происходит неавторизованное вмешательство в исполнение кода главного потока**-можно ли этого избежать?

Comment: В вопросе весьма скудно сформулирована задача приложения. Думаю, надо начать с четкого определения что мы хотим сделать, а потом думать, как это реализовать на практике. Для чего используете потоки-то?

Comment: изначальная задача приложения-создать несколько больших RTF с форматированием текста (разный размер и цвет шрифта). Можно использовать сторонние библиотеки (без richTextBox), но это получается большая отдельная работа без гарантии успеха.

Comment: @InterfaceUnknown Т.е. ваш ответ никак не решает проблему. Все "отличные статьи на английском" рассматривают случай, когда контрол создан в главном потоке, а вызовы к нему происходят из фонового (т.е. когда у конторола `InvokeRequired = true`). У топикастера же контрол создан в фоновом потоке, кросспоточных вызовов нет, `InvokeRequired = false` - он об этом прямо написал - и код из "полного ответ на вопрос" просто сделает прямой вызов. По последней ссылке вообще сказано - "You can
have a separate form on a separate thread" - т.е. вроде как все должн работать нормально. но не работает (

Comment: @PashaPash так эту проблему и не надо решать. Я об этом написал в первых двух строчках своего ответа. Отсутствие решения в данном случае связано не со сложностью, а с _совершенно неправильной постановкой задачи_. Визуальные компоненты, имеющие окна, нельзя запихивать в потоки. Да и потом, это совершенно алогично. Для чего дочерним потокам иметь non-visual components, которые в этом случае обязаны иметь родителей?
Как я и предложил, задачу надо переформулировать. Логику делать в потоках, а результаты выводить в форму главного потока.

Comment: @PashaPash "You can have a separate form on a separate thread, *but each thread needs to have it's own message pump, etc.*" - выделенное курсивом является ключевым. Без этого контекста, приведенная в твоем сообщении строчка не читается ;-)

Comment: @InterfaceUnknown этот контекст никак не влияет на возможность создания конторола. Создали контрол, начали с ним работать - он получил свой message pump в том потоке, в котором он был создан. Так что контекст там совсем ни при чем. Попробуйте запустить отдельный поток, создать в нем форму и показать ее - она отлично будет работать. Насчет необходимости иметь родителей - в винде любая кнопка, любой контрол - это окно. И его вполне можно использовать без создания формы.

Comment: @PashaPash да? Было бы интересно посмотреть на визуализацию одной кнопки без родителя, запущенной в дочернем потоке. Если вы это сможете сделать, тогда, полагаю, задача клиента будет решена ;-)

Comment: @InterfaceUnknown вы пробовали показать форму в фоновом потоке?

Comment: @PashaPash Мне кажется, что речь не об этом. А так же не о том, что пробовал я. Не хотелось бы порождать дискуссию и уходить в сторону. Я утверждаю, что реализация задачи, описанная в ОП невозможна.

Answer (score -1):

Только что увидел вот это:

> Изначальная задача -требуется в отдельном (не основном) потоке
>   сформировать большой RTF. RTF необходим, так как требуется
>   форматирование шрифта (разные размеры шрифта и проч.)

Немного смущают некорректные формулировки, из-за которых и возникают досадные ошибки и непонимания. Будьте последовательны и точны в описание задач. В частности, RTF - это формат данных, а то что вам нужно, называется, судя по всему Rich Text.

Если я правильно понимаю задачу, то происходит следующее:

1. Запускается приложение (главный поток) в виде Windows-формы. Форма - это визуальный компонент. Она служит контейнером (родителем) для всех других визуальных компонентов в приложении.
2. Затем запускается дочерний поток, в котором автор хочет разместить визуальный компонент RichTextBox *(правильно?)*

Компонент имеет окно. И для того, чтобы ему где-то "разложить свои вещички", он должен иметь родителя (parent) - тот самый контейнер, которым является форма или панель. Если нет родителя, то компонент попросту не сможет инициализироваться.

Помимо этого, и компонент, и дочерний поток должны делать маршаллинг данных для взаимодействия как друг с другом, так и с основным потоком. Как это будет выглядеть в приведенной выше схеме, лично я не представляю. Вернее, не будет это никак выглядеть.

Потоковым программистам следует понимать, что почти* весь визуальный интерактив должен реализовываться в основной форме приложения и/или в диалоговых окнах. В основном интерфейсе пользователя. А потоки - это *рабочие лошадки*, задача которых - выполнение тяжелой и времяёмкой работы (запустить выборку из базы, сказачть заголовки с IMAP-сервера, прорисовать, считать и распарсить файл и пр.). Безусловным достоинством потока является так же возмождость "разморозить" (unfreeze) экран основной формы на время исполнения тяжёлых задач.

Однако любые попытки разместить в потоках не thread-safe-контроллы будут приводить к исключениям.

**Вывод:**
Задача сформулирована неправильно; приведенными в задаче методиками ее решить нельзя. Поэтому я предложил бы автору вопроса, перепланировать подход к решению. Прежде всего задать себе вопрос - *а есть ли в данном случае реальная необходимость использовать потоки?*

*В Windows существуют техники, когда потоки непосредственно взаимодейстуют с элементами формы через message loops. Такие поток иимеют условное отношение к GUI. Например, они могут прорисовывать канву, или делать repaint по какому-нибудь событию. Эти потоки работают на низком уровне ОС и в рамках данного поста мы о них речь не ведём.

Comment: **а есть ли в данном случае реальная необходимость использовать потоки?** Есть тяжелая задача вроде см.ниже. Выполнение ее в основном потоке сразу подвешивает приложение. Думаю, это очевидно

 while (true)
       richTextBox.AppendText("a");

Comment: Тяжелую задачу нужно **разделить** на _визуальную_ и _невизуальную_ части. Второй должен заниматься поток, а в это время визуальная часть (форма) не блокируется, не подвисает и продолжает интерактивить с пользователем.

Comment: **В частности, RTF - это формат данных, а то что вам нужно, называется, судя по всему Rich Text.** Надеюсь, большинству понятней *.rtf , чем 'Rich Text' ...

Comment: А для чего тогда использовать визуальный компонент если нет визуальной части ??

Comment: для того, чтобы сформировать большой .rtf -файл

Comment: (удалил комментарий выше, дублирую) так визуальная часть не планируется и не нужна, см.первый пример кода. Правда, можно считать действия с richTextBox некими псевдо-визуальными и invoke -ать, но это тоже подвешивает основной поток и теряется вся ценность многопоточности

Comment: В RichTextBox формируем большой текст, затем делаем RichTextBox.Save(path). Получаем файл path.rtf. (Простите, если недоступно объясняю)

Comment: Да, но это не будет работать в дочернем потоке. Не будет и все. Надо искать невизуальный компонент, который может это сделать в коде потока. Наверняка есть какие-то конвертеры текста в rich text у вас в C#. Нужно найти такой класс и использовать его.

Comment: **Не будет и все**-охотно вам верю, но все-таки хочется увидеть соответствующую строку документации.

Comment: @InterfaceUnknown единственное ограничение на поток - с контролом надо работать из того потока, в котором он создан. Это легко проверить создав и показав новую форму из фонового потока. И это не имеет никакого отношения к термину thread safe. В винде каждый компонент - это окно. Никаких ограничений "обязан иметь родителя" нет. В приложении нет "главного" потока. "не будет и все" - не стоит двух ответов на вопрос, притом что довольно очевидно что работает, и глючит только в конкретном странном случае.

Comment: @PashaPash ну я уже в принципе все сказал. Мне нечего добавить. Лучшем вашим *ответом* будет, если вы приведете работающий код, отвечающий на условия задачи. А все эти рассуждения, _"все вроде бы должно работать, но глючит только в конкретном вопросе"_ - все это сказки для бедных. Работающий код в студию, коллега! Коль уж вы утверждаете, что все работает.

Comment: @PashaPash да и вот еще что: в винде далеко не каждый компонент является окном. Например, невизуальная реализация доступа к сокету, БД, файловому дескриптору и пр. Это все тоже компоненты, но они невизуальны и поэтому HWND не имеют. Так что не нужно заблуждений.

Comment: @InterfaceUnknown https://github.com/PashaPash/TwoThreads - вот вам пример приложения, в котором две формы работают в двух разных потоках, и в котором блокирование UI через вызов Thead.Sleep() внезапно не блокирует работу второй формы. RichTextBox - это окно с классом MSFTEDIT_CLASS. А теперь предлагаю перестать плодить ответы "это невозможно" и попробовать хоть как-то помочь топикастеру.

Comment: @PashaPash Предложение я принял давно. Мой поинт в том, что использование RichTextBox как это сформулировано в условии задачи - сделать нельзя. Я на этом настаиваю и по сей момент. Иными словами, так как это делается сейчас делается неправильно. Надо ли помогать этим усилиям - пусть каждый решает сам.

Comment: @PashaPash если вы иного мнения, оформите ответ? ;-) я признаю вашу правоту, а вместе мы порадемся восторгу топикастера))

Comment: @InterfaceUnknown оформил, с двумя решениями - костылем, который сработал у меня. И с запуском отдельного message pump, как предложено в KB у MS. можно радоваться )

Comment: @PashaPash Супер! Мой +1 пока не глядя, а на досуге я изучу используемые техники. Всегда найдется возможность поучиться чему-нибудь новому.