# Посоветуйте библиотеку rtf | docx с корректным форматированием перекрывающихся тегов

Tags: c#, rtf, docx

Цель — выделение (форматирование) текста различными способами (подчеркивание, разный цвет и т.д.) с корректной отработкой пересекающихся тегов. Параметры выделения берутся из регулярных выражений в виде Select(позиция начала выделения, позиция конца выделения).

Проблема работы с имеющимися библиотеками в том, что для корректного результата два перекрывающихся тега (для известных мне библиотек) нужно делить на три НЕ перекрывающихся тега, например, зеленый и подчеркнутый -> зеленый, зелено-подчеркнутый и подчеркнутый. А для однотипного форматирования, например, зеленого шрифта и красного уже исключать допустим зеленый в пределах красного т.к. шрифт не может быть одновременно зеленым и красным. Костыль становится еще более затейливым, если зеленый пересекается с красным и пересекается с подчеркнутым.

На нижеприведенной картинке показано, как теряется форматирование перекрывающихся тегов для указанных ниже библиотек:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

RichTextBox отрабатывает все правильно, но не подходит по причинам [конфликта с многопоточностью](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/442784/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-gui-richtextbox).

Нижеприведенные некорректно отрабатывают перекрывающиеся теги:

[NET RTF Writer Library in C#](http://sourceforge.net/projects/netrtfwriter/) , хотя есть Select(start, end).

[DocX is a .NET library](http://docx.codeplex.com/) не поддерживает Select->Format, только через Replace(word)->Format.

[NRTFTree](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11306/NRTFTree-A-class-library-for-RTF-processing-in-C) — поддерживает только форматирование при вводе, готовый текст нельзя отформатировать.

[PresentationFramework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/vstudio/system.windows.documents.textrange(v=vs.100).aspx) — некорректно отрабатывает Select(start, end) т.к. учитывает какие-то свои внутренние теги и выделяет не то, что нужно.

Comment: может стоит познакомиться с Nuget? http://www.nuget.org/packages?q=rtf

Comment: Не проще-ли будет моделировать последовательное наложение? Насколько вам важно, если вы весь параграф раскрасили в синий, а потом слово подсветили красным, чтобы получился фиолетовый, например? Мне кажется что этим нельзя будет пользоваться.

Comment: В сторону [Free .NET Word Library](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d3a38f74-3490-42da-bdb0-37fa5acebc36) смотрели?

Еще [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/).

И [NetOffice](http://netoffice.codeplex.com/) (требует установленного MS Office).

Comment: Странно что конфликт​ с многопоточностью, может стоит разобраться с работой в потоках - в ссылке что у вас указана на этот конфликт, описано решение (очень поверхностное,начальное), еще добавьте потокобезопасный код при работе между потоками и скорее всего все получится. Но вопрос про разные компоненты интересен, поэтому пишу в комменте.

Answer (score 1):

NPOI. Доводилось работать. Все просто шикарно и не нужен инсталлированный пакет Office. Читай доку!

https://npoi.codeplex.com/

---

https://www.nuget.org/packages/NPOI/

Answer (score 0):

- [Open XML](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk) для документов формата OpenXML(MS Office)
- [NPOI](https://github.com/tonyqus/npoi) для OpenDocument формата(OpenOffice)

[Вот таблица разницы форматов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_Office_Open_XML_%D0%B8_OpenDocument)